# How To Export/Import Large Database On MAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, export, mamp, dump

How do I export/import large database on MAMP ? Using PHPMyAdmin does not work as it supposed to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be done via terminal as below.

- In the terminal navigate to `bin` folder of MAMP using below command `cd /Applications/MAMP/library/bin`
- Use this command to export the file `./mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DATA_BASENAME] > [PATH_TO_FILE]`. EG would be `./mysqldump -u root -p my_database_name > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folder_name/exported_db.sql`
- Line should appear saying `Enter password:`. Here enter the MySQL password. keep in mind that the letters will not appear, but they are there.

If you need to import use [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) Which is a MySQL Dump Importer.

Comment: And how do you import?

Comment: You can also Import using a command similar to the export. You can read here: http://nickhardeman.com/308/export-import-large-database-using-mamp-with-terminal/

Answer (score 10):

**Turn on MAMP!**

Then, for both operations, open the terminal and type:

---

**EXPORTING:**

**`/Applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DATABASE_NAME] > [PATH_TO_SQL_FILE]`**

Then type your password in prompter (default **`root`**) and press enter.

*Example:*

`/Applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p my_database_name > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folder_name/exported_db.sql`

---

**IMPORTING** (will erase current database)**:**

**`/Applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u [USERNAME] -p [DATABASE_NAME] < [PATH_TO_SQL_FILE]`**

Then type your password in prompter (default **`root`**) and press enter.

*Example:*

`/Applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p my_database_name < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folder_name/exported_db.sql`

***/!\ Important Warning:*** *Make sure to backup your current database before doing this command in case you need a copy of it before importing. This will erase your current database!*

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Sequel Pro App if you are using MAMP PRO version to get around the defaults that phpMyAdmin gives you.

Comment: sequel pro is too slow to handle large databases

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem to dump my db from MAMP. Tried a lot of things, but always this error:
Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tried to create a [symlink](https://coderwall.com/p/w5kwzw/solved-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock), but it was already created "ln: /tmp/mysql.sock: File exists"

Thought the problem was new Mac or new MAMP.
Finally in my case (problem was in me) solution was really simple: just turn on MAMP :)
Maybe it will help someone to save a little bit time (I spent around 4 hours)

Comment: Thank you, I'll add this to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

EXPORT DATABASE FROM MAMP

Step One:

```
Open a new terminal window
```

Step Two:

```
Navigate to the MAMP install by entering the following line in terminal
cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin
Hit the enter key
```

Step Three:

```
Write the dump command
./mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DATA_BASENAME] > [PATH_TO_FILE]
Hit the enter key
Example:
./mysqldump -u root -p wp_database > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symposium10_wp/wp_db_onezero.sql
Quick tip: to navigate to a folder quickly you can drag the folder into the terminal window and it will write the location of the folder. It was a great day when someone showed me this.
```

Step Four:

```
This line of text should appear after you hit enter
Enter password:
So guess what, type your password, keep in mind that the letters will not appear, but they are there
Hit the enter key
```

Step Five:

```
Check the location of where you stored your file, if it is there, SUCCESS
Now you can import the database, which will be outlined next.
```

IMPORT DATABASE INTO MAMP

Step One:

```
Open a new terminal window
CAREFUL: This will replace all tables in the database you specify!
```

Step Two:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u [USERNAME] -p [DATABASE_NAME] < [PATH_TO_SQL_FILE]
Hit the Enter Key
Example:
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p wordpress_db < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/backupDB.sql
Quick Tip: Don’t forget that you can simply drag the file into the terminal window and it will enter the location of the file for you.
```

Step Three:

```
You should be prompted with the following line:
Enter password:
Type your password, keep in mind that the letters will not appear, but they are there
Hit the enter key
```

Step Four:

```
Check if you database was successfully imported
Navigate to phpMyAdmin in a browser
http://localhost:8888/MAMP/
```

Source: https://nickhardeman.com/308/export-import-large-database-using-mamp-with-terminal/